# How to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH from cmake for executable file?

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I compiled a executable file that is linked to a some library `a.dyld` on Mac OS, which is located in `/mylib` using cmake.
When I tried to run the program, the error message comes:

```
dyld: library not loaded a.dyld
Referenced from: path the executable file belongs
Reason: imagh not found.
```

So, if I set the environment variable `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/mylib`, the program works correctly.
But I dont want to do that since it forces every executable files to lookup the same library. (I have multiple libraries of the same name in many directories where each directory name specifies the functionality of the library.)

Is it possible to set `$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`from cmake??

Say, I have a multiple directories like

```
test_project
  |--CMakeLists.txt
  |--/src 
     |--CMakeLists.txt (build b.dyld)
     ... (programs for b.dyld)
  |--/run_test1
     |-- CMakeLitsts.txt  (link b.dyld, and a.dyld under /mylyb1)
     |-- (programs to be run)
  |--/run_test2
     |-- CMakeLitsts.txt  (link b.dyle, and a.dyld under /mylyb2)
     |-- (programs to be run)
  ... (/run_testN)
```

Comment: CMake cannot affect on environment settings when executable is run. Instead, you need to set RPATH for the executable - list of directories, "built-in" into the executable itself, where the loader will search for libraries. CMake has nice support for RPATH settings. See [CMake RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling).

Comment: So, once after the setting of RPATH for the executable, there is no need to set up DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH anymore?

Comment: Yes, for find the library at runtime it is sufficient to set RPATH. Setting variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is just another way.